# How to assign namespaces to an property of classes in typescript

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm adding a declaration file to a package for typescript。
There are some syntax like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('Sequelize');
//...
class Application {
    Sequelize = Sequelize;
}
```

So I wrote a file（index.d.ts）like this:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'; // this @types/sequelize export a namespace
//...
interface Application{
    Sequelize: Sequelize; // <---error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Sequelize' as a type.
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is saying that you want to import everything from the `sequelize` module and place it in a namespace called `Sequelize`.

You need to refer to any members imported this way as `namespace.member` - in your example that would be `Sequelize.Sequelize`, although as a personal preference I would rename the namespace to avoid the duplication.

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'; 
//...

interface Application{
    Sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe an `import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';` would allow to avoid the duplication?